# How to get javascript to run in Rspec Capybara test

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, capybara, rspec-rails

I'm building a simple Reddit Clone for practice, and would like to test to see if the ajax works and that a value on the screen is properly updated with the javascript response.  Here is the test:

```
RSpec.describe "User voting", type: :system, js: true do # Rails 5 uses describe, Rails < 5 feature
    it "updates the downvote count" do
        user = create(:user)
        login_as(user)
        link = create(:link)
        visit root_path
        expect(page).to have_css('#upvotes-1', text: '0')
        click_on(id: 'upvoter-1')
        wait_for_ajax
        expect(page).to have_css('#upvotes-1', text: '1')
   end
end
```

wait_for_ajax: (in /spec/support/wait_for_ajax.rb)

```
module WaitForAjax
    def wait_for_ajax
        Timeout.timeout(Capybara.default_max_wait_time) do
            loop until finished_all_ajax_requests?
        end     
    end

    def finished_all_ajax_requests?
        page.evaluate_script('jQuery.active').zero?
    end
end
```

Relative code from index.html.erb:

```
<%= button_tag(class: "btn btn-secondary btn-sm", id: "upvoter-#{link.id}") do %>
 <span class="fa fa-chevron-up"></span>
 Upvote
 <%= content_tag(:span, link.upvotes(), id: "upvotes-#{link.id}") %>
<% end %>
```

Controller code:

```
  def create
    @vote = current_user.votes.new(link_params)
    if @vote.vote_value == 1
      @new_value = @vote.link.upvotes
      @id_name = "#upvotes-" + @vote.link.id.to_s
    else
      @new_value = @vote.link.downvotes
      @id_name = "#downvotes-" + @vote.link.id.to_s
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      if @vote.save
        format.js   { }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
```

And finally create.js.erb:

```
console.log("create.js.erb file");

$("<%= j @id_name %>").html("<%= j @new_value.to_s %>");
```

Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'guard-rspec', require: false
  gem 'factory_bot_rails', '~> 4.0' 
  gem 'database_cleaner'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing'
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.13'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'puma'
  gem 'poltergeist'
end
```

If I load the site myself and click on the button the tally updates correctly.  However, the test fails on the second expect.  If I reload the page, the tally will update so the database is updated and #create works as expected.  The javascript doesn't get executed for some reason.  And I've tried putting a sleep after the click_on as well.  It still fails.  There seems to be something simple I'm missing here.

Comment: First, there is no need for `wait_for_ajax` since Rails will wait for the expected changes so remove that. Second - Is it actually opening a browser when you run the tests? Third- Is there a reason you’re using an obsolete version of Capybara?

Comment: I didn't think I needed the wait_for_ajax, but it was a just in case thing.  The browser doesn't open, but I thought it didn't need to.  Isn't it headless?  Third, updated my capybara to the latest, but still no dice.

Comment: Whether or not it’s headless depends on what you’ve configured. The default configuration  shouldn’t be headless https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/system-specs/system-spec

Comment: I got the browser to pop up now with selenium as the default.  Looking around it seems Poltergiest is buggy /old.  I discovered the real problem, the first click doesn't trigger the change, so if I click the button twice this test passes.  I confirmed this with manually testing.  I have a bug somewhere.

Comment: Yes - Poltergeist/Phantomjs is basically equivalent to a 7 year old version of Safari so it won’t run modern JS/CSS - definitely use Selenium with Chrome/Firefox, or one of the new CDP to Chrome drivers like Apparition

Comment: I was pulling up the new count before saving the model, so the number was always one off since it didn't include the new vote.  It's always something stupid.  Anyway thanks for your patience and walking me through this.

Comment: you’re welcome, also note that as long as you’re using Rails 5.1+ you don’t need database_cleaner and can  enable transactional testing in your RSpec config

Answer (score 0):

Switching to Selenium helped me see the problem more clearly.  Here is a pretty good tutorial that tells you how to get setup with Rails 5 / latest (late 2018) versions of things:

[A Quick Guide to Rails System Tests in RSpec](https://medium.com/table-xi/a-quick-guide-to-rails-system-tests-in-rspec-b6e9e8a8b5f6)

In the end, I used .new to create the model, but hadn't saved it, so the new vote count wasn't showing.  Moving the logic that pulled the count after the save solved the problem.

In votes_controller.rb:

```
  def create
    @vote = current_user.votes.new(link_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @vote.save
        format.js   {
          if @vote.vote_value == 1
            @new_value = @vote.link.upvotes
            @id_name = "#upvotes-" + @vote.link.id.to_s
          else
            @new_value = @vote.link.downvotes
            @id_name = "#downvotes-" + @vote.link.id.to_s
          end             
            }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
     end
   end
  end
```